# Плагин валидации телефона в зависимости от страны

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Есть ли `jQuery` плагин, который валидирует номер телефона в зависимости от выбранной ранее  страны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такие.

Например,

[International Telephone Input](https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/is-valid-number.html)

```
<input id="phone" type="tel">
<span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Правильный номер</span>
<span id="error-msg" class="hide">Не правильный номер</span>
```

JS:

```
   var telInput = $("#phone"),
      errorMsg = $("#error-msg"),
      validMsg = $("#valid-msg");

    // initialise plugin
    telInput.intlTelInput({
      utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js"
    });

    var reset = function() {
      telInput.removeClass("error");
      errorMsg.addClass("hide");
      validMsg.addClass("hide");
    };

    // on blur: validate
    telInput.blur(function() {
      reset();
      if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
        if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
          validMsg.removeClass("hide");
        } else {
          telInput.addClass("error");
          errorMsg.removeClass("hide");
        }
      }
    });

    // on keyup / change flag: reset
    telInput.on("keyup change", reset);
```

Comment: Ответы в виде ссылки не допустимы. Добавьте пример работы данной библиотеки.